# DDEV add a flask-wsgi 5000 route to existing drupal web build

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have a running drupal-9 ddev site. My goal is to add support to run a Python-Flask app at `./bot/app.py` which runs at localhost:800X.

Changes so far - this part works.
.ddev/config.yaml

- added python3, etc. `webimage_extra_packages: += [python3, python-is-python3]`
- hooks:post-start:

  - exec: "cd bot && pip install -r requirements-test.txt"

But how do i start/add the python web app?

These do not work:

- `post-start: - exec: "cd bot && python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001 --debug"`
- web_extra_daemons

```
web_extra_daemons:
  - name: "flask_dev_server"
    command: "python -m /home/loom23/.local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001 --debug"
    directory: /var/www/html/bot
```

I have seen in other docker-compose configuations where a Flask-app is started in a Dockerfile - what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

To add a Flask-WSGI route to your existing Drupal build in a DDEV environment, try this

1. Update your `.ddev/config.yaml` file to include the necessary configurations for running the Flask app after DDEV starts. It seems like you've already added the Python packages and executed a post-start hook for installing requirements.

```yaml
webimage_extra_packages: [python3, python-is-python3]
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: "cd bot && pip install -r requirements-test.txt"
    - exec: "cd bot && python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8001 --debug"
```

This assumes that your Flask app should run on port 8001. Adjust the port number as needed.

2. Ensure that your Flask app is configured to run with the specified host and port. The `--host=0.0.0.0` makes the app accessible from outside the container.
3. Verify that the Flask app is running correctly after DDEV starts.

By incorporating these changes, the Flask app should be started automatically when you run DDEV, and you can access it at `http://localhost:8001` if you set the port as 8001.

Remember to adapt the configurations based on your specific project requirements.

Comment: That starts the app, but how do i map the port? Or even better, is it possible to run the app with a route and a port but without a running 'daemon' like with the `python -m flask run...` implementation?